Entity Framework Core : how to handle using different fields from same model?
Basically what is the best practice to handle a model that points to a database that will execute stored procedures to return different columns based on if I'm an Admin (see extra columns for a CRUD) or a user (seeing the homepage).
I could just return every column, but that seems very inefficient. But when I return a subset, it yells at me because I'm not providing all of the fields in the model. And when I tried to make two models, it yelled at me that they both can't point to the same table in the database.
I'm using Blazor and .NET 8 with Entity Framework Core.
Giving a basic example here to help explain my question. I've got a table that's mapped to a model, and then 2 pages that want to interact with this model. The client side which just shows the basic info to the client, and the admin side CRUD which allows you to add/edit data and see additional columns that aren't available to the client.
Let's use a basic employee model as follows:
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Salary {get; set;}
}

I'm populating by using a simple SQL query as follows (this would be in my service/interface):
public async Task<List<Employee>> GetListAsync()
{
    var result = await _context.dbEmp
                               .FromSqlRaw<Employee>("Exec getEmployees")
                               .ToListAsync();
    return result;
}

This is for the frontend, so it basically
SELECT ID, [Name] 
FROM EmployeeTable

For the backend, the select is
public async Task<List<Employee>> GetListEditAsync()
{
    var result = await _context.dbEmp
                               .FromSqlRaw<Employee>("Exec getEmployeesEdit")
                               .ToListAsync();
    return result;
}


SELECT ID, [Name], Salary 
FROM EmployeeTable

Now for the client frontend, I get an error saying I didn't provide a value for Salary. I don't want to return that because it's just a waste of resources. I don't need the Salary to display on the customer side, but I want to display and edit it on the CRUD admin side.
What I tried in addition was:
[NotMapped]

And that worked, until I needed to use the Admin version and then it correctly didn't map my values, so they were just blank. Not something useful.
Then I tried to just make two models, one for the frontend and one for the CRUD. Except at runtime that I get an error saying I can't have two models mapped to the same table in the database.
So what's the best way to do this besides just returning all of the data in both instances?
Thanks, please let me know if you need any more info or clarification or whatnot.

You can pass a boolean flag to your stored procedure eg IsAdmin, then fetch the required fields based on the passed flag.

i'm fetching the correct fields via the stored procedure.  The problem is that the model wants all the fields to be populated.

You should really be using view models instead of using db models directly.  That way you can provide more or less data based on intent.

This is why I skipped EF and use Dapper.

Just return default values for those extras you don't want to return in non admin mode eg SELECT ID, [Name], 0 as Salary FROM EmployeeTable. If you're worrying about all those extra bytes the zeroes or empty strings are taking up on the wire, don't; the universe will soon deliver you a much bigger problem that needs your attention far more

(A row in a sql result set maps to an object of a particular type in c#; it's perfectly reasonable for EF to complain that the data it was given, that it was expecting to be representative of a person, is missing its name, head or some other thing that EF had been told it would have... And you really don't want to get into inheritance hierarchies for something as trivial as this, but that's an option too)

Final note, and perhaps this is an academic example and your real sprocs do far more, but you're not really using anything that EF was created for here; you could use Dapper if you want mapping. EF to call sproc and map is a waste; if you want different objects then use EF as intended: context.Employees.Select(e => new EmpViewModel(e.Id, e.Name)) and context.Employees.Select(e => new AdminViewModel(e.Id, e.Name, e.Salary)) - this really will vary the bytes on the wire, not transmitting those salaries, but it's not using sprocs; EF forms the select with a varying number of columns
